# ionic app uploading to app store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store

I'm trying to upload my app to app store.
I've created distribution ipas and tested - it's working fine. But when I archive and click upload to app store, it gets stuck at "authenticating with iTunes store".
I followed the steps:
Created an App ID
Created release certificates
Created Provisioning profile.
I used the Ionic Framework to build the app.
Kindly help me find the error.

Comment: Did you fix this? I've had to wait for up to 20 minutes for this process to finish, I thought it had jammed but it was doing something. Be patient and it'll work.